# Insert output of shell script into text editor?

Tags: command-line, scripts, shortcut-keys

My goal is to use the output of a bash script to insert the resulting string into a text file using a system-defined shortcut key.

The script (see below) works just fine in the terminal. But when I trigger it from my shortcut key (I'm using: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, in case that matters), I don't get anything "out" from the script. The editor (e.g., gedit) seems to "blink", but nothing happens. I'm guessing that the script is running, but that I'm not "finishing" the script properly for this use(?).

This is the script: it takes a unix timestamp (output of `date +%s`), converts that to base62, then returns that last four characters of the resulting string. (For the curious, I use this to generate reasonable anchors for footnotes in "Markdown" text.)

```
#!/bin/bash
# takes unix timestamp and converts to base62
# HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472352/232251

function u2b {
  v=$(date +%s)
  BASE62=($(echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}))
  for i in $(bc <<< "obase=62; $v"); do echo -n ${BASE62[$(( 10#$i ))]}
  done 
}
r=$(u2b)
echo ${r: -4}
```

I have tried the last line with `printf ${r: -4}`, but that doesn't help.

How can I persuade this script/key-combination to provide "input" for my editor? (I'm using vanilla latest Ubuntu, btw.)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `xdotool type` in the first instance - if you can't get that to work, you could fall back to inserting the text into the X selection buffer using `xclip` or `xsel` and the using any of the existing paste options inside the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some help from [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393164/99759), and incorporating that into the script with a bit of delay (maybe I need a faster routine!) gives me just the result needed to input the result of this script into the active window:

```
#!/bin/bash
# takes unix timestamp and converts to base62
# HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472352 | https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393164

function u2b {
  v=$(date +%s)
  BASE62=($(echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}))
  for i in $(bc <<< "obase=62; $v"); do echo -n ${BASE62[$(( 10#$i ))]}
  done 
}
r=$(u2b)
o=$(echo ${r: -4})

windowid=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
sleep 0.5 && xdotool windowactivate --sync $windowid type "$o"
```

The changes from the original post are all found in the last three lines, as so:

- capture the desired string to a variable;
- grab the ID of the current window;
- let script run & "type" the output string into the current window.

I especially like that this doesn't need to mess with an intermediate file, or use the clipboard in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Change the original bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# takes unix timestamp and converts to base62
# HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472352/232251

function u2b {
  v=$(date +%s)
  BASE62=($(echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}))
  for i in $(bc <<< "obase=62; $v"); do echo -n ${BASE62[$(( 10#$i ))]}
  done 
}
r=$(u2b)
result=$(echo ${r: -4})
echo $result # for testing only, this line can be optionally deleted afterwards
gedit - <<< $result # redirect output into gedit
```

The second to last line that says `echo $result` is only used for testing the script. It can optionally be deleted.

Comment: Right - I can confirm that behaviour, too. It was helpful to see the process you were using, and it pointed me in the direction of the solution I posted. Thanks!